# Strip parity bits in C

Tags: c

Say I have a stream of bits with 8 bits of data followed by 2 parity bits (pattern repeats).

Example (x are parity bits):

> 0001 0001  xx00 0100  01xx 0001  0001 xx00 ...

should become

> 0001 0001  0001 0001  0001 0001 ...

I feel like this should be easy and I'm just over thinking it, but how do you go about stripping these parity bits?

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: @Phonon data is read into a buffer, the length of the data is known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky bit here is C doesn't let you work with bits easily, only bytes.  I am going to assume that your `char` holds 8 bits (check `CHAR_BIT` in `limits.h`) -- this is the case on almost all modern systems.  The least common multiple of 8 and 10 is 40, so you want to work in a buffer of at least 40 bits that you can do integer arithmetic on as a whole -- in practice that means a 64-bit type.  So here's one way to do it, reading from stdin and writing to stdout.  Handling streams that are not a multiple of 40 bits in length is left as an exercise.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    uint_least64_t buffer;

    for (;;)
    {
       buffer = 0;
       /* read in 4 10-bit units = 5 8-bit units */
       c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break;
       buffer = ((buffer << 8) | c);
       c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break;
       buffer = ((buffer << 8) | c);
       c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break;
       buffer = ((buffer << 8) | c);
       c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break;
       buffer = ((buffer << 8) | c);
       c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break;
       buffer = ((buffer << 8) | c);

       /* write out the non-parity bits */
       putchar((buffer & 0xFF00000000ULL) >> 32);
       putchar((buffer & 0x003FC00000ULL) >> 22);
       putchar((buffer & 0x00000FF000ULL) >> 12);
       putchar((buffer & 0x00000003FCULL) >>  2);
    }
    /* deal with incomplete block here */
    return 0;
}
```

... If you wanted to be really clever you would *check* those parity bits before you threw them away, although then you would have to come up with something constructive to do when (not if) the checksum failed.

Comment: Would Duff's device be applicable in handling incomplete blocks? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Comment: @josec, please don't ever use anything like that in production code.

Comment: @josec, above & beyond Carl's warning, I don't see how such a structure would be helpful. A regular switch statement, keyed off of a count of the 8-byte units read and using fall-through would do the trick.

Comment: Duff's device, in its original form, isn't applicable here because you're dealing with a short read at the end, not misalignment at the beginning.  Jump-into-the-middle-of-a-sequence control logic (perhaps replacing the `break`s with `goto`s) might be usable but I don't immediately see how to prevent it from emitting the incomplete block in the wrong order (LIFO instead of FIFO).

Comment: I have the same issue but on 32bit machine. I have 8 data bits followed by 1 parity bit and pattern repeats as in the OP's question

Comment: @dubnde Unfortunately, the least common multiple of 8 and 9 is 72, which is bigger than 64, so my technique wouldn't help you even if you had 64-bit registers.  There is another way to do this, involving a state machine, but this comment box is too small.  Recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Zack. I have ask the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978215/strip-parity-bits-in-c-from-8-bits-of-data-followed-by-1-parity-bit

Answer (score -1):

I would define a bitfield struct in C, then use it to 'frame' the data buffer, extracting out just the useful bits. Something like this:

```
struct tframe {
     unsigned data: 8;
     unsigned control: 2;
}

struct tframe * frames = &buf;

/* Iterate and write 'data' field to wherever */
...
```

You are working with your own data so code portability will not be an issue.

Comment: Besides the portability problems you mentioned, this attempt at using a bitfield won't even work - you can still only point it at byte boundaries. Objects can't have fractional sizes.

Comment: It would work if expanded to a sequence of four "data"+"control" items, so that the whole was a whole number of 8-bit bytes.  Modulo structure packing issues, which all by themselves are a reason not to use this technique if you ask me.

Comment: And of course if you do that, it doesn't get you out of the short-read problem.

Comment: Yes, i thought byte boundaries might be a problem but havent done C in awhile! OP didn't mention anything about the size of his data buffer or what the storage type is, so I assume he is aware he is going to have short read problems regardless (0 bit/byte padding at the end?).