# Strip parity bits in C from 8 bits of data followed by 1 parity bit

Tags: c, parity

I have a buffer of bits with 8 bits of data followed by 1 parity bit. This pattern repeats itself. The buffer is currently stored as an array of octets.

Example (p are parity bits):

0001 0001 p000 0100 0p00 0001 00p01 1100 ...

should become

0001 0001 0000 1000 0000 0100 0111 00 ...

Basically, I need to strip of every ninth bit to just obtain the data bits. How can I achieve this?

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538039/strip-parity-bits-in-c) asked here sometime back.

This is on a 32 bit machine so the solution to the related question may not be applicable. The maximum possible number of bits is 45 i.e. 5 data octets

This is what I have tried so far. I have created a "boolean" array and added the bits into the array based on the the bitset of the octet. I then look at every ninth index of the array and through it away. Then move the remaining array down one index. Then I've got only the data bits left. I was thinking there may be better ways of doing this.

Comment: The code in the answer to the related question can really help if you modify it a bit. Why didn't you try it?

Comment: Even if you have a 32 bit machine, you should be able to use 64 bit data types...

Comment: thanks. The machine has no 64 bit data types.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the numerous responses. I will try these approaches. I hope to come back to the forum and give some response on which one I have picked, and accept and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of having an array of bits is good. Just implement the array of bits by a 32-bit number (buffer).

To remove a bit from the middle of the buffer:

```
void remove_bit(uint32_t* buffer, int* occupancy, int pos)
{
    assert(*occupancy > 0);
    uint32_t high_half = *buffer >> pos >> 1;
    uint32_t low_half = *buffer << (32 - pos) >> (32 - pos);
    *buffer = high_half | low_half;
    --*occupancy;
}
```

To add a byte to the buffer:

```
void add_byte(uint32_t* buffer, int* occupancy, uint8_t byte)
{
    assert(*occupancy <= 24);
    *buffer = (*buffer << 8) | byte;
    *occupancy += 8;
}
```

To remove a byte from the buffer:

```
uint8_t remove_byte(uint32_t* buffer, int* occupancy)
{
    uint8_t result = *buffer >> (*occupancy - 8);
    assert(*occupancy >= 8);
    *occupancy -= 8;
    return result;
}
```

You will have to arrange the calls so that the buffer never overflows. For example:

```
buffer = 0;
occupancy = 0;
add_byte(buffer, occupancy, *input++);
add_byte(buffer, occupancy, *input++);
remove_bit(buffer, occupancy, 7);
*output++ = remove_byte(buffer, occupancy);
add_byte(buffer, occupancy, *input++);
remove_bit(buffer, occupancy, 6);
*output++ = remove_byte(buffer, occupancy);
... (there are only 6 input bytes, so this should be easy)
```

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo-code (since you're not providing any proof you've tried something), I would probably do it like this, for simplicity:

- View the data (with parity bits included) as a *stream of bits*
- While there are bits left to read:

  - Read the next 8 bits
  - Write to the output
  - Read one more bit, and discard it

This "lifts you up" from worrying about reading bytes, which no longer is a useful operation since your bytes are interleaved with bits you want to discard.

Answer (score 1):

I have written helper functions to read unaligned bit buffers (this was for AVC streams, see original source [here](https://github.com/noirotm/flvmeta/blob/master/src/avc.c)). The code itself is GPL, I'm pasting interesting (modified) bits here.

```
typedef struct bit_buffer_ {
  uint8_t * start;
  size_t size;
  uint8_t * current;
  uint8_t read_bits;
} bit_buffer;

/* reads one bit and returns its value as a 8-bit integer */
uint8_t get_bit(bit_buffer * bb) {
  uint8_t ret;
  ret = (*(bb->current) >> (7 - bb->read_bits)) & 0x1;
  if (bb->read_bits == 7) {
      bb->read_bits = 0;
      bb->current++;
  }
  else {
      bb->read_bits++;
  }
  return ret;
}

/* reads up to 32 bits and returns the value as a 32-bit integer */
uint32_t get_bits(bit_buffer * bb, size_t nbits) {
  uint32_t i, ret;
  ret = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < nbits; i++) {
    ret = (ret << 1) + get_bit(bb);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

You can use the structure like this:

```
uint_8 * buffer;
size_t buffer_size;
/* assumes buffer points to your data */

bit_buffer bb;
bb.start = buffer;
bb.size = buffer_size;
bb.current = buffer;
bb.read_bits = 0;

uint32_t value = get_bits(&bb, 8);
uint8_t parity = get_bit(&bb);

uint32_t value2 = get_bits(&bb, 8);
uint8_t parity2 = get_bit(&bb);

/* etc */
```

I must stress that this code is quite perfectible, proper bound checking must be implemented, but it works fine in my use-case.

I leave it as an exercise to you to implement a proper bit buffer reader using this for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
void RemoveParity(unsigned char buffer[], int size)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i + j < size; i++)
    {
        if (offset == 0)
        {
            printf("%u\n", buffer[i + j - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned char left = buffer[i + j - 1] << offset;
            unsigned char right = buffer[i + j] >> (8 - offset);
            printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)(left | right));
        }
        offset++;
        if (offset == 8)
        {
            offset = 0;
            j++; // advance buffer (8 parity bit consumed)
        }
    }
}
```